# Удаление элементов из массива при снятии чекмаркера с ячейки

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile-development

В таблице из нескольких секций, при снятии чекмаркеров установленных в ячейках, из массива удаляю элементы нажатой ячейки.

`removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)` работает беспорядочно, и то только после многократного снятия чекмаркеров с большого количества нажатых ячеек приложение падает, то после первого снятия. Не могу до конца понять, как правильно указать в `removeAtIndex` индекс нажатой ячейки. На скрине например приложение упало только при снятии чекмаркера с последней нажатой ячейки (в массиве оставались элементы одной ячейки)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код удаления можно посомтреть

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Здравствуйте. На вопрос уже дан ответ, поэтому его нежелательно удалять — это приведёт к потере усилий, вложенных другим участником. Я немного отформатировал вопрос, чтобы он лучше читался.

Comment: Если это необходимо, можно отвязать вопрос от вашей учетной записи, но это крайняя мера. Жду ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда пусть остается...

Answer (score 3):

У вас есть загруженная таблица, допустим с 10 элементами ( 10 элементов в массиве), когда вы пишите `exercise.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)`, то вы даете команду удалить элемент из массива, но этот же элемент используется для отображения в таблице - это раз проблема. Другая может возникать, когда при первом вызове у вас в `numberOfRowsInSection` вернуло 10, а массив теперь имеет 9 элементов, отсюда в методе `cellFor...` у вас выходит за диапазон массива.

Пути решения:

- Использовать метод: [deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)
- После удаления эл. из массива обновлять таблицу `reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

Также можно сохранять статус выделено/не выделено для каждого элемента (вместо удаления). Потом выбираешь из массива только выделенные элементы и используешь их по назначению.